# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) on a simple Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding this password manager program and keep getting this error message when I use the view function:

```
    File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\password_manager.py", line 7, in view
    user, passw = data.split("|")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is the program so far:

```
master_pwd = input("What is the master password?")

def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User:", user, "Password:", passw)

        

def add():
    name = input("Account name: ")
    pwd = input("Password: ")

    with open("passwords.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + pwd + "\n")
    

while True:
    mode = input("Would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add)? Press q to quit. ").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break
    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("Invalid mode.")
        continue
```

I tried using the .split() method to one variable at a time but it also resulted in the error.
I thought the problem could be caused by the comma in  `user, passw = data.split("|")` being deprecated, but I failed to find an alternative.

Comment: Why do you think the comma is deprecated?

Comment: Add a if condition between data = line.strip() and user,pass = data.split("|") (ex: if data: user, passw = data.split("|")

Comment: What if someone uses "|" in a user name or password? You may be better off using a CSV file instead of your own `split` because those details have been sorted out for you.

Comment: The error means that there is more than one `|` in the file, so the split gets more than 2 values.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I thought it could be a possibility since the code is from a few years old video and because it didn't have issues using one variable at a time. Thank you for asking this question, it helped me question the conclusion I got to.

Comment: @zer0c00l It was solved after I removed the contents of the passwords.txt file. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll still take it into consideration.

Comment: @tdelaney Although I'm short of time right now, I will research what you suggested me (since it might be quite useful) and I promise I'll get back to you on it. Thank you.

Comment: @tdelaney And regarding your second comment, that was exactly the reason it wasn't working. If you place this comment as an answer I'll gladly mark it as the solution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @LuisM. - I noticed others have already mentioned that in the answer, so I won't add another one. The remaining question is whether the thing that wrote the file had any rules about extra bars. If you move to `csv`, you'll also have to change the writer to `csv` and trash (or hand fix) the existing user db.

Answer (score 2):

The `.split()` function is returning more than 2 values in a list and therefore cannot be unpacked into only 2 variables. Maybe you have a password or username with a `|` in it which would cause that.

I suggest to simply `print(data.split('|'))` for a visual of what is happening. It will probably print out a list with more than two values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your suggestion on the second paragraph but for visual purposes, I'd rather have the contents be displayed in a more explicit way so it can be easily understood by anyone who uses the program.

Answer (score 2):

Check your password file to be sure there aren't  "|" characters in a username or password that are creating additional splits.

If your data is good, you could catch the remaining elements in a list:

```
user, passw, *other = data.split("|")
```

Comment: It was solved after I deleted the entire contents of the 'passwords.txt' file. It now works as intended. Thank you.